# Converting date to character format in SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm trying to convert a date format stored m/d/yyyy to a 'yyyymmdd' character format, without the need to cast the date column every time I want to use the column in my query.

Currently I'm casting and formatting dates as chars: `((cast(cast(invitation_date as CHAR(8)) as date format 'YYYYMMDD'))`.

Is there a way to convert the data column once and call the converted character value later in the query?

I'm using Teradata in Aqua Data Studio 13.0.3.

Comment: Is the source column a DATE or a CHAR?

Comment: @dnoeth: the source column invitation_date is stored as a decimal (length 8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If source is a DECIMAL yyyymmdd you can do

```
CAST(invitation_date - 19000000 AS DATE) AS newcol
```

Teradata allows an alias to be used in any place, so you can simply do

```
WHERE newcol > DATE
```

Of course best case would be to change those columns to DATE during load.

Answer (score 1):

```
select to_char(field, 'yyyy-mm--dd hh:mm:ss') from table;
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but it didn't work. `select invitationdate(field, 'yyyymmdd') from table;` resulted in the following error: "Syntax error: Data Type "field" does not match a Defined Type name."

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to File->Options -> Results Format -> Teradata. Then select the datatype Date and enter yyyyMMdd. Your result set will now return the specified date format. Let me know if this will solve your issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is not what I'm trying to achieve as they way dates are stored in tables differs per table. Sometimes dates are stored as decimals, sometimes as dates or strings.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put it like this, it simply won't work:

```
select invitationdate(field, 'yyyymmdd')
```

try this instead :

```
SELECT to_char(column_date, 'yyyy/mm/dd') from table;
```

as "man" said. please pay attention to the undescore (`_`) character; not this (`-`) one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a longer but in a way simpler way that works

select
yourdate
    ,cast((extract(year from yourdate)*100 + extract(month from yourdate))*100 + extract(day from yourdate) as char(8)) as yyyymmdd
from ...