# How to format Date as this format 'DD.MM.Y4'?

Tags: teradata, datetime-format

I have been trying several ways to represent date as this way  **10.12.2014**. But I didn't find proper way to solve this problem, Teradata's FAQ gives some ways how to use `FORMAT`, but none how to solve my problem.

So let we have

```
SELECT DATE'2014-12-04'
```

How can we make it looks like **10.12.2014**

P.S. `SELECT DATE'2014-12-04' (FORMAT 'DD.MM.Y4')` returns 2014-12-04 and used to check queries this [site](http://tunweb.teradata.ws/SQLAssistantWeb/login.aspx?isTrial=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this :

```
 SELECT CAST('2014-12-04' AS DATE) (FORMAT 'dd.mm.yyyy') (CHAR(10))
```

I hope help you

Comment: This works fine, in addition I found such way here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21914444/converting-date-to-character-format-in-sql  It's to set required view in a SQL Assistant`s options.